# How to remove "Not Available" in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to remove the "Not Available" in the following data frame, but when I change `Number` to numeric using the following code, the "Not Available" becomes `4`:

```
c1 <- c("India", "America", "China", "Europe", "Japan")
c2 <- c(2.3, 3.5, "Not Available", 1.2, 1.2)
data <- data.frame(Name=c1, Number=c2)
data$Number <- as.numeric(data$Number)
```

The result is:

```
data

##      Name Number
## 1   India      2
## 2 America      3
## 3   China      4
## 4  Europe      1
## 5   Japan      1
```

How can I remove the "Not Available" rows in this data frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because:

1. An R `data.frame` only allows a single class of data per column.
2. When you create a `data.frame`, the default behaviour is for `character` columns to be coerced to `factor`, which are stored as numeric values (corresponding to factor levels) with labels. Your `c2` vector is a `character` vector since it has a character element ("Not Available"), and as such the `Number` column of `data` is a `factor` column.
3. When you coerce a factor directly to `numeric`, the resulting numbers indicate the factor levels.

To achieve the behaviour you're after, you can either prevent the character data from being coerced to a factor when creating the data.frame:

```
data <- data.frame(Name=c1, Number=c2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data$Number <- as.numeric(data$Number)

data
##      Name        Number
## 1   India           2.3
## 2 America           3.5
## 3   China            NA
## 4  Europe           1.2
## 5   Japan           1.2
```

Alternatively, you can coerce the factor to numeric via character:

```
data$Number <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Number))
```

Neither of these options will "remove the Not Available rows", as you've requested. They just convert the "Not Available" elements (and any other "text" elements of the `Number` column) to `NA`. To *remove* the rows containing "Not Available", you can do:

```
data <- data.frame(Name=c1, Number=c2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
na.omit(data)
```

or, using your original `data` object:

```
data <- data.frame(Name=c1, Number=c2)
data[data$Number != 'Not Available', ]
```

Answer (score 2):

We could also read the dataset with `na.strings = "Not Available"` in the `read.csv/read.table` so that it will return as `NA` value which can be removed with `?is.na` or `?complete.cases` or `?na.omit`.

```
df1 <- read.csv("file.csv", na.strings="Not Available")
res <- df1[complete.cases(df1$Number),]
```